# Asymptotic behaviour of a sequence with finite sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm working on$$
u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2+(n-k)^2}
$$
to find out an asymptotic behaviour as $n \rightarrow +\infty.$ I've already seen that $u_n$ tends to $0$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm assuming $n>0$?

Comment: Yes:$n \rightarrow +\infty.$

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$
nu_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n}{k^2 + (n-k)^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(k/n)^2+(1-k/n)^2}\sim\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dk}{k^2+(1-k)^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$; so $u_n \sim \pi/(2n)$ in that limit.

Answer (score 3):

Factor out $n^2$. You get $\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{k^2/n^2+(1-k/n)^2}$ and if you relable $u=k/n$ you are effectively approximating the integral

$$\int_0^1\frac{du}{u^2+(1-u)^2}.$$

It should be easy to evaluate so your series tends to a constant divided by $n$, eg it is $O(1/n)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{u_{n}\equiv\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n}{1 \over k^{2} + \pars{n - k}^{2}}\,.\quad}$ 
>   Asymptotic behavior as $\ds{n\ \to\ \infty:\ {\large ?}}$

\begin{align}
u_{n}&\equiv
\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over k^{2} + \pars{n - k}^{2}}-
{1 \over \pars{k + n + 1}^{2} + \pars{k + 1}^{2}}}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2} + \pars{n - k}^{2}}
-\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2} + \pars{k + n}^{2}}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over n^{2}}+
\bracks{\color{#c00000}{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2} + \pars{n - k}^{2}}}
- \pars{n\ \to\ -n}}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Then,
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2} + \pars{n - k}^{2}}}
> =\half\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2} -nk + n^{2}/2}
> =\half\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \bracks{k - {\rm r}_{-}\pars{n}}
> \bracks{k - {\rm r}_{+}\pars{n}}}
> \\[5mm]&\mbox{where}\quad {\rm r}_{\pm}\pars{n} \equiv {1 \pm \ic \over 2}\,n
> \quad\mbox{such that:}
> \\[5mm]&\color{#c00000}{%
> \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2} + \pars{n - k}^{2}}}
> =\half\,{\Psi\pars{-{\rm r}_{-}\pars{n}} - \Psi\pars{-{\rm r}_{+}\pars{n}}
> \over \bracks{-{\rm r}_{-}\pars{n}} - \bracks{-{\rm r}_{+}\pars{n}}}
> \end{align}
>   $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the *Digamma Function* and
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{%
> \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2} + \pars{n - k}^{2}}}
> =-\,\half\,{2\ic\,\Im\Psi\pars{-{\rm r}_{+}\pars{n}} \over \ic n}
> =-\,{\Im\Psi\pars{-{\rm r}_{+}\pars{n}} \over n}
> \\[5mm]&=-\,{1 \over n}\,\Im\Psi\pars{{-1 - \ic \over 2}\,n}
> \end{align}

Replacing in expression $\pars{1}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large u_{n}}&={1 \over n^{2}} + \braces{%
-\,{1 \over n}\,\Im\Psi\pars{{-1 - \ic \over 2}\,n}
-\bracks{{1 \over n}\,\Im\Psi\pars{{1 + \ic \over 2}\,n}}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large-\,{1 \over n}\bracks{%
\Im\Psi\pars{{-1 - \ic \over 2}\,n} + \Im\Psi\pars{{1 + \ic \over 2}\,n}}
+
{1 \over n^{2}}}
\end{align}

> With the
>   [Digamma Asymptotic Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm)
>   $$
> \Psi\pars{z}\sim
> \ln\pars{z} - {1 \over 2z} - {1 \over 12 z^{2}} + \cdots\,,\qquad
> \verts{z}\ \to\ \infty\quad \mbox{in}\quad \verts{{\rm arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi
> $$

we'll have
\begin{align}
u_{n}&\sim -\,{1 \over n}\bracks{-\,{3\pi \over 4} + {\pi \over 4}} + {1 \over n^{2}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over 2}\,{1 \over n} + {1 \over n^{2}}}\,,\qquad
n\ \to\ \infty
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Set $\displaystyle f(x):=\frac{1}{x^2+(1-x)^2}$. We have
$$
u_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
$$
Since $f$  is a continuous function on $[0,1]$, $nu_n$ is then a related Riemann sum, as $n$ tends to $+\infty$, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
n\:u_n &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\\\\
&=\int_0^1f(x)\:dx+\mathcal{o}(1)\\\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2+(1-x)^2}\:dx+\mathcal{o}(1)\\\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{2}{1+(2x-1)^2}\:dx+\mathcal{o}(1)\\\\
&=\arctan(2\times 1-1)-\arctan(2\times 0-1)+\mathcal{o}(1)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}+\mathcal{o}(1)
\end{align} 
$$
giving the asymptotic expansion
$$ u_n=\frac{\pi}{2n}+\mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Comment: ${\rm o}\left(\,{1 \over n}\,\right)$ should be ${\rm o}\left(\,{1 \over n^{2}}\,\right)$. See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1033376/85343).

Comment: @FelixMarin You mean: $\displaystyle \mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ Yes, I knew it. I just gave a **quick** answer, without using for example Euler-Maclaurin formula which would have led to an extended asymptotic behaviour. Thank you! (+1 for your answer)

Comment: Fine. Thanks a lot.